# Magento data model - "one or more images" field

Tags: magento, model

I have created a custom extension in Magento.

I would like to be able to attach one or more images to an item. The clunky way would be to add a bunch of image fields and ignore the empty ones but this is obviously limited and not very tidy.

Question 1) Is there a generic term for this technique? I've tried googling for solutions but haven't found a way to phrase it that doesn't bring up a bunch of unrelated things.

Question 2) Is there a way to do this simply in Magento or will I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need your own.
Maybe you should just create Models which store a list of image names and a sort order along with a foreign key to your current model. 
then you could just have a collection of images loaded by the id of you current model and sorted with an order by clause.
Simply use a methods like these

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('foreign_key_column', array('eq' => $foreignKey))
           ->setOrder('sort_order');
```